# i need to enter c inbetween shell script for the command to continue

Tags: command-line

I am using a command in shell script ,it needs 'c' key to be entered for the command to continue.

I tried below and it never hits c,

```
command  
sleep 60

printf "c\n"
```

but it never hits c after 60s,when I manually hit c,I see c printed after the command execution is complete.

Can u help with this.

Comment: You start the command and since it waits for the key it never returns. So the rest of the script is never executed. Besides that, you'd just print a "c" to stdout, which has nothing to do with the command's input. you might try to pipe the "c" to the command or use stdin redirection.

Comment: Try `command <<< 'c' ` something like this you should try.

Comment: Not sure what the context is, but normally the command: `xdotool type c && sleep .1 && xdotool key Return` should do the job. That is: assuming `xdotool` is installed (`sudo apt-get install xdotool`). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't have xdotool...I need to wait for 60s after the command to hit c

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't / don't want to install it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP mentioned he was on RHEL 5 in a comment. Possible solutions obviously differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
(sleep 60;echo c)|command
```

Comment: an echoed / printed string or character will not be considered as input. OP seems to need that, since he tried: `c\n`(including next line). The exact context is not really clear to me however.

Comment: OP still needs to clarify what the command is, and *if* it will take the piped input.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm...I am on RHEL 5 and xdotool is not supported.Is there any otherway except for pipe